# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-2)!}(2n+1)x^{2n}$ to function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, solution-verification, power-series

I want to calculate $3-\frac{5}{2}+\frac{7}{24}-\frac{9}{720}+...$, while using $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-2)!}(2n+1)x^{2n}$.

Here is my attempt:

Firs I proved that the radius of converges for this series is $R= \infty$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-2)!}(2n+1)x^{2n} =~_{k=n-1} ~ = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+2}}{(2k)!}(2k+3)x^{2k+2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k)!}(x^{2k+3})'$$

$$= (\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k)!}x^{2k+3})'= (x^3 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k)!}x^{2k})'=(x^3 \cos(x))'=3x^2 \cos(x)-x^3 \sin(x)$$

So $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-2)!}(2n+1)x^{2n}=3x^2 \cos(x)-x^3 \sin(x)$.

If I did everything correct, than I should find a value for $x$ which will help me to calculate the initial sum.

Did I do it ok?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: $2n+1=(2n-2)+3$. This seems to indicate that you are in the right direction.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It didn't lead me to anything, just 2 series instead of one

Comment: Actually $x=1$ suffices and your series will make the desired terms

Comment: @Aryan Yes! Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, but which ones ?

Answer (score 2):

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-2)!}(2n+1)x^{2n}$$
Let $k=n-1$, then
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k (2k+3)\frac{x^{2k+2}}{(2k)!}$$
We konw that $$x^3\cos x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+3}}{(2k)!}$$
D.w.r.t. $x$, then
$$-x^3\sin x+3x^2 \cos x=S$$
OP's summation is verified. The sum of the numerical series is nothing but
$$3\cos 1-\sin 1$$ which is when $x=1$.